# Question About Redirection Https to Another Webiste on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, redirect

I got following problem when configuring website using ubuntu / apache :

I have two websites, let says its xxx.com and yyy.com

My problem is, we decide to merge the website into yyy.com, thus do redirection for all request from xxx.com to yyy.com

Then I put this on my configuration file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxx.com
Redirect / https://www.yyy.com/en/xxx
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.xxx.com
Redirect / https://www.yyy.com/en/xxx
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are the result when i try to access in url :

- xxx.com moved to new website (success)
- [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com) moved to new website (succeess)
- h t t p s://www.xxx.com FAILED -> I got this error on my Chrome : "This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset."

I don't know if this related, but my xxx.com is using Positive SSL Wildcard.

Can anyone help me on why my redirection not working when I'm access my xxx website using https://?

I'm sorry if the question is very basic. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So far you have two Virtual Hosts for port 80 set up. HTTPS uses port 443. So unless you set up a Virtual Host to listen on that port as well, there _is_ nothing Chrome could connect to.

Comment: Btw., you don't need two separate VHosts to cover `xxx.com` and `www.xxx.com`- you can use the `ServerAlias` directive to specify alternate host names within the same VHost.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thank you for your explanation. I add following configuration :

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName xxx.com
Redirect / https://www.yyy.com/en/xxx
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.xxx.com
Redirect / https://www.yyy.com/en/xxx
</VirtualHost>

but it seems the redirection still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the browser connect to the HTTPS version of those URLs to begin with? That will only happen, if you have a valid SSL certificate for those domains, and have it properly configured in these vhosts. Otherwise, the browser will not be able to create a secure connection to the server, and will break off the connection, before they even get to "speak HTTP" to each other. So in that case, you won't be able to redirect anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there is some misconfiguration on one of our subdomain part.
Not sure why, but when I fix the misconfiguration, somehow the redirection (who actually doesn't call the subdomain) works